# blender 2.8 First bake failed

Tags: baking

So I followed Andrew Price's baking instructions in the anvil tutorial and below is my result.  Any suggestions as to what I did wrong?[image]

UV:
[image: https://i.imgur.com/5B6PIIX.png]

[image]

Comment: Show your UV layout please. Are you trying to bake a normal map or a bump map? If you are trying to bake a normal map like in the tutorial you are in the wrong baking mode as normal maps have RGB color information and this is black and white.

Comment: It's a normal map.  [Here you go... ](https://imgur./a/Gibi1gY)

Comment: Looks like your baking isn't using your UVs. Did you unwrap your low poly or high poly mesh? Are you correctly selecting them before baking (high then low)? Please upload your .blend file for further help right here: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Okay the .blend file is up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Shader editor create a new blank image in the low poly anvil's material and set its panel active (select it and its white outline must be appear). Select the high poly anvil then the low poly (so the hp must be orange, the lp must be yellow) and click on bake in the render properties panel. You have to increase the ray distance a little before the baking (probably mine wasn't the optimal).

[image]